# Why there is such a big lag between kubernetes pod finished and job completed status

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

I've started to work with kubernetes jobs recently, and currently trying to understand the workflow.

So I'm taking the very first example from official documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/:

```
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl:5.34.0
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

and applying it

```
kubectl apply -f https://kubernetes.io/examples/controllers/job.yaml
```

Then I'm waiting for the job to finish:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/pi
```

And check the pod's status after that (omitting unimportant staff for readability):

```
kubectl describe pod
Name:         pi-jm9hw
Namespace:    pi-job
Start Time:   Sat, 15 Apr 2023 10:54:09 +0400
.....
Containers:
  pi:
.....
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 15 Apr 2023 10:54:21 +0400
      Finished:     Sat, 15 Apr 2023 10:54:25 +0400

Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  84s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned pi-job/pi-jm9hw to gke-apps-dev-default-pool-a3ff2d21-l4gc
  Normal  Pulling    84s   kubelet            Pulling image "perl:5.34.0"
  Normal  Pulled     72s   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "perl:5.34.0" in 11.465562943s
  Normal  Created    72s   kubelet            Created container pi
  Normal  Started    72s   kubelet            Started container pi
```

and here is the job's status:

```
kubectl describe job
Name:             pi
Namespace:        pi-job
....
Start Time:       Sat, 15 Apr 2023 10:54:09 +0400
Completed At:     Sat, 15 Apr 2023 10:54:31 +0400
Duration:         22s
Pods Statuses:    0 Active (0 Ready) / 1 Succeeded / 0 Failed
.....
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age    From            Message
  ----    ------            ----   ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  3m5s   job-controller  Created pod: pi-jm9hw
  Normal  Completed         2m43s  job-controller  Job completed
```

Thing, that I can't understand, is why there is such a lag between job's finish state and job's completion state.

Hence:

The pod started at 10:54:21 and finished at 10:54:25, completing in 4 seconds.

The job's state changed to completed at 10:54:31, in 6 seconds after pod finished.

Thus, job's lag (period between pod's completion and job's completion) is 1.5 times bigger than pod's work time itself, which is too big for my taste, and for the app I'm currently working on.

So, my question is: what does the job wait for and why doesn't it complete right after the job.

P.S. Hypotheses, that I've tested and rejected:

1. The pod run takes more time to complete, than `describe` command shows. I've tested different job (`busybox` image with `sleep 5` command). The pod takes exactly 5 seconds to complete, the job - about 8-10 seconds.
2. The job finishes before *official* `completed at` date. Wrong assumption either, as `kubectl wait` command waits full time, i.e. 3-5 extra seconds after the pod is finishes.
3. The problem is with my kubernetes cluster. I've tried this flow on different clusters: `docker-desktop`, `k3s` on vps, `gcp` and the result is always the same - several seconds lag.

Comment: Not sure the answer here but it could be that the job includes the time to initialize and terminate the pod, but the pod time only includes the time it was running.

Answer (score 0):

The [controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/) is responsible for creating the Pod object when you create a Job, and for updating the Job when the Pod is completed.

You could try to increase the performance of your Kubernetes cluster